# How can I call c lib fn which takes struct pointer arguments from csharp

Tags: c#, c, pointers, struct, ffi

Extract from c header:

```c
struct ArgvArgcResult {
  char*  buffer;
  char** argv;
  uint   argc;
};
bool get_argv_and_argc_of_pid(pid_t pid, struct ArgvArgcResult* result);
```

Notably the c "strings" cannot be relied upon to have any specific encoding so representing them as C# strings may not be possible, rather I think `byte[]` is right, but I'm not sure how to indicate that the length is not known at compile time.

Trying to express the c struct in C# I'm at a loss what types to use for the `char*` and `char**`:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ArgvArgcResult {
    public char*  buffer;
    public char** argv;
    public ulong  argc;
}
```

Also what does a pointer to a struct look like when calling a c fn from c# for the dllimport?

```cs
[DllImport("libgetargv.dylib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] static extern bool get_argv_and_argc_of_pid(nuint pid, struct ArgvArgcResult* result);
```

Comment: How is the C# side going to release the memory taken up by the `argv` array? Aside: have you connsidered just using `CommandLineToArgV` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw

Comment: @Charlieface I have other functions (including functions to free the memory) that I can work out how to convert based on this struct/function. I cannot use any win32 api because this is a platform specific library for macOS. Also that api appears to be for the running process and this function is for other processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` in C/C++ is 8-bit, so you need `byte` for that. You can pass it as a `byte[]` array, but `char*` can also be passed as an ANSI string. You seem to be doing your own memory management, so you can pass `argv` as a pointer to a pointer.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct ArgvArgcResult
{
    public string buffer;
    public IntPtr argv;
    public ulong argc;
}
```

Pass the struct as `ref`

```cs
[DllImport("libgetargv.dylib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern bool get_argv_and_argc_of_pid(
  nuint pid,
  ref ArgvArgcResult result);
```

And when you use it, you can read `argv` like this

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < result.argc; i++)
{
    var ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(argv, IntPtr.Size * i);
    var str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
    // do stuff
}
// don't forget to free memory
```